# drop down Value clearing is not working as expected Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

Team,

I am trying clear my drop down after adding my fields to the respective panels .

Here is screen shot for the reference

[image]

With my current code the dropdown is working for the first & second  time when i select the field and select panel drop down working as per expectation

For the Third time The dropdown is not clearing it's still showing the previous one which I selected

Here is my Html code

```
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="isLabelChecked">
                        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="panelName" (ngModelChange)="onDropDownChange($event)">
                            <mat-label>Panel Name</mat-label>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let formGroupNames of formData.groups" [value]="formGroupNames.formGroupName">
                                {{formGroupNames.formGroupName}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Here is my ts code for that

```
 onItemDrop(formgroupname: string, field:FField) {
    console.log('asdfsdf' + formgroupname);
    let fg = this.form.get(formgroupname) as FormGroup;    
   console.log(fg);
   // this.fields = [...this.fields, field];
   this.formData.groups.find(value => {
    if(value.formGroupName === formgroupname) {
        value.fields.push(field);
      }
   })
fg.addControl(
  field.formControlName,
  new FormControl('', field.required ? Validators?.required : null)
);
this.panelName = "";
```

}

Comment: 1-What if you depend on a boolean flag and uses *ngIf this will remove the select. 
2- you can empty formData.groups list after you finish.

Comment: @MahmoudNasr can you help me on the code wise

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe reset the form if the mat-options are wrapped inside form tag that is=>

**this is how i did it**

as for the html i have a form =>

```
 <form #formDirective="ngForm">
  <!--here is mat-dropdown and other fields-->
</form>
```

Then in ts file=>

```
@ViewChild('formDirective') private formDirective: NgForm; //formDirective reference class variable
```

**Using below code to reset:**

```
this.formDirective.resetForm();
```

*I think you can add it* =>

```
   onItemDrop(formgroupname: string, field:FField) {
        console.log('asdfsdf' + formgroupname);
        let fg = this.form.get(formgroupname) as FormGroup;    
       console.log(fg);
       // this.fields = [...this.fields, field];
       this.formData.groups.find(value => {
        if(value.formGroupName === formgroupname) {
            value.fields.push(field);
          }
       })
    fg.addControl(
      field.formControlName,
      new FormControl('', field.required ? Validators?.required : null)
    );
    this.panelName = "";
    this.formDirective.resetForm(); //here probably  

}
```

Try if it works for you if all conditions are statisfied

Comment: thanks for your reply can you please come online if it is possible so i can explain more here